# iMovie question (possibly need a different apple product? IDK)

Tags: video, imovie, animation

Okay, this question is a bit of a doozy. 
I decided to try my hand at making a rotoscoping animation. That's basically an animation created using real film as a base.

The original video is 16500 frames long, 24 frames per second. I'm only animating half of those frames. 
I used "FireAlpaca" to draw each and every one of the still images that would be used in this video.

Do i use imovie to make this video? Obviously since there's less frames, it's going to by quicker, correct ? How do I make it so that there are only 12 frames per second instead of 24, and therefore be able to make my video at the same length as the original film I'm using as the basis for this animation?

Essentially it's just an extremely fast slideshow. Can I do this in imovie? Final Cut Pro? What do I do????

Comment: What have you tried so far, did you try to do a short 5 second sample in iMovie for instance? Does it work for you that way or did you run into issues?

Comment: @Patrix , I don't know where to begin with this. I need to edit in frames, not seconds, and I'm not sure how to do that. I'm unfamiliar with imovie or any other editing software.

Comment: So you are more looking into "how to get started with iMovie"? Which again begs the question: what have you tried so far? Did you look at the intro articles on apple.com?

Comment: @Patrix - Yeah, I've been looking around but I'm not sure where to begin with anything. I wasn't sure what to start with, i figured imovie would be the simplest???
Again, it's a very specific quesiton that is hard to find an answer for, I've looked up everything but there's no real distinct answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [How can I combine 30,000 images into a timelapse movie?](https://superuser.com/questions/249101/how-can-i-combine-30-000-images-into-a-timelapse-movie)

## ffmpeg

In answers to this question the community suggest using the open source tools [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) or [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). For example the `ffmpeg` approach is:

> This will create a video slideshow (using video codec libx264) from series of png images, named named img001.png, img002.png, img003.png, …
>
> Each image will have a duration of 5 seconds, change the variable according to your choice.
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
> ```
>
> If your images have four digits, use `%04d`, etc. If your images do not have this pattern, you can use shell globs, at least on Linux and OS X:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i 'time-lapse-files/*.JPG' …
> ```
>
> You can also change the output framerate by specifying another `-r` after the input.

Also see:

- [ffmpeg: create a video from images](https://superuser.com/questions/624567/ffmpeg-create-a-video-from-images)
- http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/ for a researchers use of ffmpeg to combine individual images into a movie.

### Homebrew

You can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to get `ffmpeg` onto your Mac:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install `ffmpeg` with:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```